# Embedding an image with PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I'm creating a simple website with php scripts as just kind of a little project and I want to be able to show pictures on my site. I've visited some sites before that show their images [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZw8X.png) (hopefully you know what I'm talking about by looking at that picture). Is that program/script/whatever free, and if it is, is it newbie friendly? And are there any other good-looking ways to embed a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about scripts like [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/).

It's free and easy to integrate if you follow the instructions. Search for lightbox alternatives if you want a different look or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Its not really PHP, but more javascript. You want to take a look at [jquery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)